# How do I apply to more the one class the same function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, class, shortcut

I this is my code:
html part :

```
<div class="a">1</div>
<div class="b">2</div>
<div class="c">3</div>
<div class="d">4</div>
```

this is the js part :

```
        $(".a").hide();
        $(".b").hide();
        $(".c").hide();
        $(".d").hide();
```

I wonder if there is any shortcuts to do this? I don't want to write four times `$(".classname").show()`. thx

Comment: why my post is voted down ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. comma seprated multiple selector:

```
$(".a,.b,.c,.d").hide();
```

Comment: @Chester remember, you can always use any kind of CSS selectors in jquery!

Comment: @Milind Anantwar, thx for the post, can you tell me why my post is voted down ?

Comment: @Chester Why are you worrying about the downvotes too much.? Post a better question next time and get upvotes for that.

Comment: @Chester: i have no idea . But solution to something like do exists on SO and other sources.

Comment: any ideea why this post is voted down ? I can;t post anymore and I have to check my post to change it